# How to notate the final element in a sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, notation

I'm having troubles putting this in to words here, but here it goes: If I have a sequence of numbers, called $A$ where $A$ is a sequence of numbers that don't seem to have a pattern, how can I notate the last element in the sequence without knowing how many elements are in the sequence?
For Example: If I have $A = \langle 3, 1, 5, \ldots, 9, 5, 4\rangle$, I do not know how many elements there are but I know that last element is 4. Is there any way to notate this 4 in the sequence?

Comment: You shouldn't use curly brackets like that for a sequence, as your sequence looks exactly like a set, which is unordered.

Comment: @GFauxPas What would you use instead?

Comment: If you knew that your sequence didn't repeat numbers, you could cheat and define $A_n = n$ so that $A_{100} = 100$ (and there isn't any ambiguity as to which $100$ is meant since it isn't repeated). This doesn't feel very satisfactory though.

Comment: $\langle \cdots \rangle$, `\langle \rangle`, or  parentheses.

Comment: @GFauxPas Turns out I have the wrong wording. What I actually meant WAS a set. Not a sequence. Thank you

Comment: @CameronWilliams I used the wrong word. I was actually referring to sets, not sequences. Sorry.

Comment: @JamieSanborn Even better! In sets, elements are not repeated so $100$ can only appear once in your set for example. Then $A_n = n$ is perfectly fine but still not very satisfactory.

Comment: For a sequence of length $|S|$, you could say the $|S|^{th}$ element. For a set, this does not make sense.

Comment: Just restated my question entirely. (These above comments might not make sense)

Comment: There exists one unique n which if n then there is no y such that y is an ordered relational element supra n?  Not sure how to convert that to LaTex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just lacking a way to express the number of elements in the sequence, it seems. You can use $\#A$ or $|A|$ or state that the sequence has length $N$. Then append the suffix $^{th}$.

The Python programming language uses the following indexing convention: elements are numbered $0$ to $N-1$, but negative indexes can be used. The element $A_{-1}$ is the last one, $A_{-2}$ the beforelast one and so on until $A_{-N}$.

Comment: My problem isn't that I'm lacking the number of elements. The reason I did this is because I didn't want people to answer with $A_N$ where $N$ is the number of elements. I suppose this is just the way to go though. Thank you.

Comment: How do you denote the second element ?

Comment: Wouldn't it be $A_2$ ?

Comment: Then what's wrong with $A_N$ ? And what about $A_{\#A}$ or $A_{|A|}$ ?

Comment: I never really thought about it. Something about it just seems unappealing. I guess I'm weird like that.